# The UINavigationBar is pushed out of the screen when the keyboard opens (UITextView)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

**Description** : I got a simple `UIViewController` that contains only one big `UITextView`. There are 4 simple constraints : top, right, bottom and left. Nothing fancy.

**What is my problem** : When the user starts to type text into the `UITextView`, the `keyboard` opens and the `UINavigationBar` gets out of the screen. I would like the `UINavigationBar` stays at the same place.

**Demo** :

- `UIViewController's` background is **blue**
- `UITextView's` background is **red**
- Please note that everything seems fine when the `keyboard` appears at *the first time*, but then the `UINavigationBar` problem appears...

**EDIT :**

Here is a demo project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lMtXNWLyEXDQMy7eeyu-sQrmsTja-tvO/view?usp=sharing

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem was occuring because of `IQKeyboardManager`.

I solved my problem doing the following :

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = false;
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager) from Nuget on your iOS project. Then enable it in the AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
   //... 

   IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;

   return true;
}
```

**Update:**

I create a demo without using stroryboard ,and you can refer it .

in AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
   // create a new window instance based on the screen size
   Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
   Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new MainViewController());
   IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;

   // make the window visible
   Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

   return true;
}
```

> in MainViewController

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  View = new UniversalView();

  base.ViewDidLoad();

  Title = "Title";

  IQTextView textView = new IQTextView() {

      Frame = new CGRect(20, 90, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 40, 626),
      BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
      Text = "xxx",
      Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14),
  };

  View.AddSubview(textView);

  // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
}
```

Your issue maybe because of you use auto layout . And you can use [Masonry](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/iOS/Masonry) from Nuget .

Comment: I'm already using `IQKeyboardManager`, and the `UITextView` (with the red background) inherits `IQTextView`.

Comment: I made a demo project and added it to my original post !

Comment: Check https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/iOS/Masonry

Comment: Masonry is just a nicer syntax to write autolayout constraints. The problem will be the same if I remove my constraints in Interface Builder and replace them by code using Masonry.